# How To Get SIngle Row Value from multiple duplicate value in SQL Database by using MVC4

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Three tables

1-Category having two fields: 
(i)Id (ii)Name

2-Products having 4 fields:
(i)Id (ii)P_Name (iii)Category_Id (iv)Description

3-ImagePath having 3 fields:
(i)Id (ii)Product_Id (iii)Imagepath

These three tables have foreign Key Relationship like Category table's ID is Stored In Product Table And Product Table ID is Stored in Imagepath Table.
On the basis of the Product_Id multiple images are stored in ImagePath Table like the image shown below:

[image: Snapshot]

Now I want to fetch a single images on the basis of the Product_Id
Please Help me to solve this problem
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you writing an SQL query for fetching the data from the database? In that case, you may need to use "Group BY" and "First()" function in your SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  select * from (select Products.id,Imagepath,(ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by Products .id )) as rowno   from Category ,Products , ImagePath  where  ImagePath.Product_Id  = Products.id and  Products.Category_Id =Category.id   ) t where rowno=1
```

You can change the output by changing the value of rowno

Comment: Can u just explain the first select statement that Products.Id and Imagepath is responce which fields in the table

Comment: Products.Id is the primary key in product table,Since id is used in 3 tables in order to avoid ambiguity it is so used. Imagepath is a field in imagepath table

Comment: Befour ur code i wrote this line of code to display the values on the basisi of the Category_Id.Now Iwant to Fetch single Data on the basis of the Cat_Id from ImagePath Table

Comment: i wrote a store procedure to get the value on the basis of the CategoryID i want to fetch A single value from the Multiple value present in the ImagePath Table `alter proc sp_getImgByCat
  @catid int
  as
  begin
   select p.Id,p.Cat_Id,p.P_Name,img.ImagePath from P_Product p INNER JOIN P_ImagePath img ON p.Id=img.P_Id where p.Cat_Id=@catid
   
  end`